# Is there a limit to the number of times Stasis can be used on an enemy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I accidentally ended up in a Gold multiplayer game against Cerberus this morning, and I don't think I've ever seen so many Phantoms in one place. I noticed that sometimes Stasis didn't seem to work on Phantoms that I'd already used it on once or twice.

**Is there a limit to the number of times a single enemy can be frozen by Stasis? If so, is it affected by difficulty?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stasis does have a limit.  From the [wiki entry](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Stasis) on stasis:

> Stasis Bubble will stop working against enemies who've been hit with it three times already, or received sufficient damage. It is highly recommended that you kill them before it becomes ineffective, especially when facing tougher foes.

Comment: For reference, I can kill phantoms with 3-4 shots of my Carnifex, which usually means only 1 bubble. The one thing you want to make sure to not do is stasis an enemy - and then just let them be. If they're frozen, kill it!

Comment: @RavenDreamer I love stasis bubble while on my infiltrator, since I can 1 shot phantoms if I hit their head.